# Jquery change width of div

Tags: jquery, css

I want to change the width of elements rendered using following code. I have tried adding style width:xxpx element in definition and try defining a new css class to invail. I want both the containers under main container to be of same size. But the following code is rendering approximately 40-60. I am using the style sheets from jquery ui(jquery-ui-1.7.1.custom.css).

```
 this.container = $('<div class="ui-multiselect ui-helper-clearfix ui-widget" ></div>').insertAfter(this.element);
 this.availableContainer = $('<div class="ui-widget-content list-container available"></div>').appendTo(this.container);
 this.selectedContainer = $('<div class="ui-widget-content list-container selected"></div>').appendTo(this.container);
```

Help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var newWidth = this.container.width() / 2;    //I assume you want the child divs to be half the size of the parent?
this.availableContainer.width(newWidth);
this.selectedContainer.width(newWidth);
```

This is how to do what you asked, change the width of the DIVs with jQuery.

You should probably keep bashing away at the CSS and try and get the styles set with your stylesheet if your website/app is expected to function without JavaScript.

Link to working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Phu6y/5/

Comment: Huh? Well in that case you probably need to provide a bit more information, as the problem isn't with the JavaScript, but elsewhere. What I posted DOES work, check the jsfiddle link I just edited in. If it isnt working for you, the issue is somewhere else.

Comment: One of those eh... Good luck :)